# A Windows 7 tool to create an image from my bootable USB stick

Tags: disk-utility, compact-flash, disk-cloning

I am looking for an efficient and preferrably free tool
to take a full copy of my USB stick and make a disk image from it
with possibility to write back to it.

Actually I have a CF-Disk and I am mounting it through adapter so in Windows it's looks like a USB flash disk. I can't just copy and paste the contents of that disk since it's bootable.

So I need to make a full backup.

At a later time I wanna be able to restore it to either that CF-Disk or Another one but similiar disk.

Looking for Windows 7 compatible program

Comment: using DriveImage XML. I hope it works fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes [DriveImage XML](http://www.runtime.org/driveimage-xml.htm) works fine. It's free and it can do what you want.

You can also look into [Acronis TrueImage](http://www.acronis.com/homecomputing/products/trueimage/).